# Why number of systemctl tasks more then number of process threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, service, systemd, systemctl

I have my multithread application running under systemd service.
When it runs without workload number of threads in `/proc/<Main PID>/status` and in output of systemctl are same

`systemctl show -p TasksCurrent <ServiceName>
  TasksCurrent=287
cat /proc/<Main PID>/status | grep Threads
  Threads:        287`

In some cases when workload increases, number of `Threads` in `/proc/<pid>/status` varies from `287` to `295`(it is normal, additional threads are created during workflow) but number of `TasksCurrent` in `systemctl` output constantly varies from `~500` to `~3000`

Service has only one process in CGroup but also it has some other services in dependencies like `Requires`, `Wants` and `BindsTo`. All of those services has ***constant*** number of `TasksCurrent`, for one of them it is `~3500`(and it equals to number of threads in it's processes), for all others it is `1`

**Question:**
Why number of service's tasks is not equal to number of threads in this service's only process?

Comment: Reading `systemd` source code I believe it basically does `r = cg_get_attribute("pids", u->cgroup_path, "pids.current", &v);` to display the `TasksCurrent` value. So it just reads the content of `pids.current` from relevant control group, so probably counting everything in the `cgroup`, hence the difference you may see with just counting `threads` that by definition are for a single process (PID). There is not a lot of documentation about that :-(